# A Very Strange StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

Before asking this question , i spent around half an hour on google , but since i didn't find a solution i thought i maybe should ask here. 
So basically i'm using Java Reader to read a text file and converting each line of information into an Object that i called Nation ( With a constructor of course ) and making an array out of all those objects. 
The problem is that a single line on my text file goes to 75 characters. But i get an error telling me that the length is only 68 ! So Here's the part of the code where i read informations from the file :

```
static int lireRemplir (String nomFichier, Nation[] nations)
    throws IOException
{
    boolean existeFichier = true;
    int n =0;

    FileReader fr = null;

    try {
        fr = new FileReader(nomFichier);
    }
    catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException erreur) {
        System.out.println("Probléme avec l'ouverture du fichier " + nomFichier);
        existeFichier = false;
    }

    if (existeFichier) {

        BufferedReader entree = new BufferedReader(fr);
        boolean finFichier = false;

        while (!finFichier) {

            String uneLigne = entree.readLine();

            if (uneLigne == null) {
                finFichier=true;
            }
            else {

                nations[n] = new Nation(uneLigne.charAt(0),uneLigne.substring(55,63),
                       uneLigne.substring(64,74),uneLigne.substring(1,15),uneLigne.substring(36,54));

                n++;
            }
        }

        entree.close();
    }

    return n;
}
```

The Error i get is :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   begin 64, end 74, length 68

Since i'm new here i tried to post an image of my text but i couldn't, so i'll just try to hand write an exemple:

2ETATS-UNIS                 WASHINGTON          9629047       291289535

4CHINE                       PEKIN               9596960      1273111290

3JAPON                              KYOTO               377835    12761000

There is alot of space between the words it's like an array!

If i change the 74 to 68 i get a result when i try to print my array , but the information is missing.

Here's my constructor:

```
public Nation(char codeContinent, String superficie, String population, String nom, String capitale) {
    this.codeContinent = codeContinent;
    this.superficie = superficie;
    this.population = population;
    this.nom = nom;
    this.capitale = capitale;
}
```

I hope you could help me with this! If you need to know more about my code let me know ! Thank you very much.

Comment: `The problem is that a single line on my text file goes to 75 characters` - perhaps that's not true for all the lines of your file. It's easy enough to check if there are shorter lines. Just print the length of each line.

Comment: As mentioned, just add a `System.out.println(uneLigne.length())` as the first statement of the `else` block

Comment: Not credible. `java.lang.String.substring()` is rather well tested for the last 22 years. Clearly you are wrong about the length of the line. If you disagree please provide conclusive evidence.

Comment: Somewhere in your file, there's a line with only 68 characters.  Count again.  And make sure you're using your platform's default character encoding when you count.

Comment: I tried to println the length of each line , and i comes out that there's only one line with 68characters all the rest are either 71,72 or 73

Comment: Yes. Exactly.  You get the error on the line with 68 characters.

Comment: You did not provide examples of the data you are extracting the substring from. Is it necessary to use substring? Maybe it is possible to extract the data you need by using a combination of `contains()` and `indexOf()` or even a `regExp`, independent of the string-length?

Comment: The data i'm extracting is like this :
2ETATS-UNIS                         WASHINGTON          9629047  291289535
it's an array so there's alot of space between words , do you have any other suggestion , i'm literally new to java

Comment: Please do not post this very important information in the comments, where it might easily overlooked by other readers. Put it into the question and add several examples, so the readers understand the structure of the data.

Comment: Please post a verbatim example of the code you want to process. You have written "there is a lot of space between words", how much space? How is the space filled? Add the examples as code-blocks, so you wont lose the spaces to formatting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simpliest way to solve your problem is to change the 74 by uneLigne.length. 
Here's the new code.

```
nations[n] = new Nation(uneLigne.charAt(0),uneLigne.substring(55,63),
                       uneLigne.substring(64,uneLigne.length),uneLigne.substring(1,15),uneLigne.substring(36,54));
```

Comment: This will work if your string is guaranteed to be >64 characters, otherwise, you will get the same exception.

Comment: I understood by what he posted that the txt file is like an array , so there's always a line number where the column begins and wich is 64 for his case.

Comment: He said that "there is alot of space between words", but he did not define how much space. So there might be examples that have less than 64 characters, which would not work with this solution.

Comment: Ahmed is right , it always starts at a specific line number , so it solved my problem without changing much in my code! thanks for your answers all of you

Answer (score 1):

To avoid Runtime Exceptions, you need to be careful with your code. In cases where you are dealing with indexes of a String or an array, please check for length of the String to be greater or equal to the maximum index you are using. Enclose you code that is throwing the exception within:

```
    if(uneLigne.length() > 74) {
        nations[n] = new Nation(uneLigne.charAt(0),uneLigne.substring(55,63),
                       uneLigne.substring(64,74),uneLigne.substring(1,15),uneLigne.substring(36,54));
    } else {
       //your logic to handle the line with less than 74 characters
    }
```

This will ensure your code does not break even if any line is smaller than expected characters.

**______________________________________________________________________________**

***Another approach***

Adding the comment as an answer:

The other way would be to use **split()** method of String class or **StringTokenizer** class to get the array/tokens if the line is delimited with space or some other character. With this, you need not break the string using substring() method where you need to worry about the lengths and possible Runtime.

Check the below code snippet using split() method, for each line you read from file, you probably have to do this way:

```
Nation nation = null;
String uneLigne = "2ETATS-UNIS WASHINGTON 9629047 291289535";
String[] strArray = uneLigne.split(" ");
if(strArray.length > 3) {
    nation = new Nation(getContinentCodeFromFirstElement(strArray[0]), strArray[1], 
        strArray[2], strArray[3], strArray[4]);
}

//getContinentCodeFromFirstElement(strArray[0]) is your private method to pick the code from your first token/element.
```

Comment: I see ! But isn't there any other solution than to handle it length by length ?

Comment: @Django: See my comment on the question itself: You should provide examples of the data you are using. Maybe there IS a way to accomplish what you want without using hardcoded numbers.
This solution also does not gather the information in strings with `length < 74` ... maybe this is not wanted?

Comment: The other way would be to use split() method of String class or StringTokenizer class to get the tokens if the line is delimited with space or some other character. With this, you need not break the string using substring() method.

Comment: I just posted an exemple of my data !

Comment: For each line, you probably have to do this way: ```String str= "2ETATS-UNIS WASHINGTON 9629047 291289535";
  String[] strArray = str.split(" ");
  if(strArray.length > 3) {
   Nation nation = new Nation(getCodeFromFirstElement(strArray[0]), strArray[1], strArray[2], strArray[3], strArray[4])
  }```

Comment: Alright ! Thank you very much Hamena for your concrete exemple , i had to write extra line of codes but it's working now ! Since no one is downvoting this question, i'll just stick with your answer!

Comment: Thank you too JavaYouth!

Comment: @Django: I did not answer your question but JavaYouth did. If he puts the code from his comment into his answer, I will gladly upvote it.

Comment: Added the code from comment to answer as an alternate approach